# How do I use angular ng-hide based on the page/route that I am currently on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

have an angular application that I want to hide one of the 'included views' if the main view is the homepage view.

```
<div id="page" ng-class="{ showNav: $root.showNav }">
    <header id="pageHeader" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" data-ng-include="'views/includes/header.html'"></header>
    <div id="pageHero" ng-show='$rootScope.fullView' ng-controller="MainsearchCtrl" data-ng-include="'views/mainSearch.html'"></div>
    <div id="pageContent" ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

You can inject either `$route` or `$location` into your controller, fetch needed value from one of these services and use it in `ng-show` or `ng-if`.

Example of using `$route` and `$location` you can see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route#example).

Here is one of possible ways of doing it:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/one', {
        controller: 'routeController',
        templateUrl: 'routeTemplate.html'
      }).
      when('/two', {
        controller: 'routeController',
        templateUrl: 'routeTemplate.html'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/one'
      })
  }]).
  controller('routeController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.showPageHero = $location.path() === '/one';
  }]);
```

**routeTemplate.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>Route Template</h1>
  <div ng-include="'hero.html'" ng-if="showPageHero"></div>
  <div ng-include="'content.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sZlZaz3LQILJcCywB1EB?p=preview

Comment: This is exacly what I am looking to do, only the div that contains teh ng-if is actually on the index page and therefore is not working.

Comment: Is it valid to have multiple $scope methods within the controller? Example:
  `controller('routeController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {                                                           
    $scope.showPageHero = $location.path() === '/one';
    $scope.showNewHeader = $location.path() === '/two';
  }]);`

Comment: @KyleVassella Sure, these are not methods, but boolean values, and you may have multiple of them on the same `$scope`. So, it's totally valid.

Answer (score 5):

Just use ng-show with a negative expression:

```
<div id=includedView ng-view="included" ng-show="location != '/main'"></div>
```

You'll have to set the value of `location` on your controller `$scope` in your controller; possibly using the `$route` or `$location` providers.

Comment: Not really a very useful answer unless you already understand `$route` and `$location`. In which case you can probably figure this out for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you use routes you can run some logic on each route change in the `resolve` block in the routeprovider.

In the example below I'm using a custom SystemService service that stores the location and in turn broadcasts an event on $rootScope. In this example the navigation is outside of the views managed by the routed controllers and has its own controller:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html',
      controller: 'WelcomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        load: function(SystemService){            
          SystemService.fireNavEvent({showNav:false,location:'/'});            
        }
      }
    }).
    when('/other', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/other.html',
      controller: 'ElseCtrl',
      resolve: {
        load: function(SystemService){            
          SystemService.fireNavEvent({showNav:true,location:'/other'});            
        }
      }
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
```

// in SystemServce:

```
function fireNavEvent(obj){
    this.showNav = obj.showNav;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('navEvent',obj);
}
```

// then in the navigtion controller:

```
$scope.$on("navEvent", function(evt,args){
  $scope.showNav = SystemService.showNav;
  // also some logic to set the active nav item based on location
});
```

There are other ways to achieve this, for example you could just broadcast the navigation change on `$rootScope` directly from the routes config.

You could also inject $location into your controller and set the visibility based on that.